# How do I solve this React Error (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

./src/Card/Card.jsx
Syntax error: Unexpected token (5:19)

```js
 3 | 
  4 | const Card = (props) => (
> 5 |     <div className-"card-container">
    |                    ^
  6 |         <div classnName ="card">
  7 |             <div className ="front">
  8 |                 <div classnName="Que">Question</div>
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be a `=` not `-` before your div `className`, see the following:

```js
  3 | 
  4 | const Card = (props) => (
> 5 |     <div className="card-container">
  6 |         <div classnName="card">
  7 |             <div className="front">
  8 |                 <div classnName="Que">Question</div>
```

I would highly recommend you reading thru the official docs to learn more about JSX:

[Introducing JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

[JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: I don't think a recommendation to read is necessary. Reading official docs won't help avoid syntax errors

Comment: After learning the basic of JSX, you'll be able to avoid syntax errors like this :)

Answer (score -1):

It should be '='.

```
<div className='card-container">
```

And also correct the spelling of className in second and fourth div. Otherwise the class wond be captured in css but it won't be throwing syntax errors.

```
 <div className ="card">
```

Answer (score -2):

Use babel to transform your code using CMD or in conjunction with webpack.

Comment: React uses a jsx transformation with a script tag like `<script type="text/jsx">`. Using babel or webpack are nice but won't help here